# command line; delete static file in a folders who begins with certain character

Tags: command-line, scripting, wildcard, delete-file

I have hundreds of folders like 
170102texta
170204textb
180306textc
180408textd

these folders and many subfolder is the file test.txt present. 
I would like to to delete all the "test.txt" files but only in the folders who begins with "17.."

every advice is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

you just have to run rm -rf {pattern}*

```
C02XF0N6JG5M:test kkadam$ ls -lrt
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 kkadam staff 64 Feb 13 21:00 11test
drwxr-xr-x 2 kkadam staff 64 Feb 13 21:00 11b
drwxr-xr-x 2 kkadam staff 64 Feb 13 21:00 11c
C02XF0N6JG5M:test kkadam$ rm -rf 11*
C02XF0N6JG5M:test kkadam$ ls -lrt
total 0
```

Comment: sorry I want to use it in DOS.

Comment: yo may try del 11*